# AJAX get page not on manifest

Tags: jquery, ajax, webkit, manifest

With a cached HTML page and JQuery, It seems it is impossible to get a page from the server that was not listed on the manifest. Any time I try to access a page not on the manifest, it always returns null, or "". Has anyone managed to access a page not on the manifest? If so, how? This code will deployed on Webkit(nightly build).

Comment: How are you making the requests for uncached pages, AJAX or in an IFRAME or ...?

Answer (score 0):

Got It! Pretty simple too...
I forgot to add the following to cache

```
CACHE MANIFEST
NETWORK:
*
CACHE:
index.php
...
```

The NETWORK: allows ajax to get any pages not on the cache

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm AJAX GETting simple JSON results from cache-manifest page, getting status 0.